# jQuery: Width() Of Inline-Block H1 Sometimes Equals 0. Suggestions?

Tags: jquery, css

I want a form's max-width to equal 80% of an H1's width. The H1's width will vary based on screen size, but jQuery is often detecting it as 0.

```
#maximage .in-slide-content h1 
{
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```
(function($)
{
    $(window).on( "load", function()
    {
        var h1_width_tp = $('#maximage .mc-image:first-child .in-slide-content h1').width();
        var form_maxwidth_tp = .8 * h1_width_tp;
        console.log("maxwidth: " + form_maxwidth_tp);
        $('form.idx-omnibar-form').css('max-width', form_maxwidth_tp);
    });
    
})( jQuery );
```

When you view [this page](https://www.meganmicco.com/megan-micco-realtor-learn-the-difference-test/) and open the browser's dev console, you'll see a value listed for "maxwidth." If the value is not 0, refresh the page. 0 comes up pretty often. Any suggestions?

THANKS!

Comment: Please add a [MRE] with a sample of the HTML that this applies to. Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained so you need to include all the relevant code, and when you have solved the problem on your site it can no longer be seen so this question will not be as useful to others in future.

Answer (score 1):

it is because you did not defined the width of H1 Tag, define the width for h1 like
width: 80% or you can do width: 80vw if you want as a view port width;

```css
#maximage .in-slide-content h1 
{
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```